# Gain of this current mirror amplifier in Cadence is way off from my expectation

Tags: current-mirror

Calculate the gain of this current mirror amplifier. This is from Youtube video (https://youtu.be/Jmu02dErhdg?t=894).

[image]

Here is my small signal analysis of this circuit.

[image]

\$M_{ref}\$ always works in saturation region.

$$I_{ref} = \frac{1} {2} \mu_p C_{ox} \frac{W} {L} (V_{gs} - V_{th})^2$$

The gate voltage of M1 is DC because of the current source \$I_{ref}\$.

In M1, gate and source are both grounded \$V_{gs}\$ = 0, so there is no voltage controlled current source.

The overall current which flows M1 and M2 is the same, so we can derive the following equation:

$$-\frac{V_{out}} {r_{o1}} = \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}} + V_{in} g_{m2}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = - \frac{g_{m2}} {1/r_{o1} + 1/r_{o2}} = -g_{m2} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o2})$$

The following is cadence virtuoso schematics.

[image: virtuoso]

Testbench for this circuit is here.

[image]

***The gain of this circuit is much less than 1!!!***

[image]

Here is the gain in numbers.

[image]

Updated testbench.

[image]

Updated results according to advice from G36.

[image]

**I got this current through M1 is not the same as \$I_{ref}\$. You could see \$I_{D1}\$ (My M1 and M2 is not the same as the one from Youtube schematics, they are interchanged) was acting like square wave. Is current mirror wrong.  What's wrong here?**

[image]

The following is the current following through M2 when \$I_{ref} = 1 \mu A\$.
[image]

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: What does this have to do with Cadence?

Comment: @G36 Please see my updated post

Comment: @Hearth Please see my updated post

Comment: It is not a surprise because you did not ensure the "correct setting" of the transistors operating point (DC quiescent point).  Also the low R0 value will kill the gain as well.

Comment: @G36 What value R0 do you recommend? How can I know the transistor operating point? Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this example:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sNJ4.png

Comment: @G36 Please take a look at my updated simulation.

Comment: You need to choose (tweak) the R1 (8Meg) value (increase it) so that the DC voltage at the output is 2.5V.

Comment: @G36 Could you see my updates on the current through M1? Why is it not the same as \$I_{ref}\$?

Comment: @kile what is your supply voltage?  Are you looking at a case where the DC bias for your gate on the NMOS is such that the drain is supply/2?

Comment: @mapplejacks 10 volts for Vdd

Comment: @kile what is V(Iref)? What is the actual desired reference current? What value are you seeing (you cut off units on currents)?  Those transistors look small; have you sized them appropriately for the value of current you're carrying?

Comment: @mapplejacks \$I_{ref}\$ is an ideal current source so I don't think  there is any voltage

Comment: @kile What do you mean?  It's a node.  Of course it has a voltage.  I am talking about your PMOS gate node.  My guess is that your FET current density is way too high, but it's difficult to confirm this without clear answers from your end, like what Iref is, both in terms of bias voltage and gate current.  It also looks like you're using 3 volt FETs, and if that's a drain rating, they're overvoltaged.

Comment: @mapplejacks \$I_{ref} = 1 \mu A\$ Is this too high according to you?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've calculated the gain, the way to simulate it is this:

- Choose a sufficiently small Vi voltage swing (e.g. 1mV)
- Measure the AC output voltage swing on Vout
- divide the swing in Vout over the Vi swing and you have your gain (remember it should have a negative sign for a common source amp)

EDIT: Based on your update showing lack of gain, your low side device isn't biased correctly.  In fact, it looks like Vout is sitting at your rail because the gate of your NMOS is in cutoff (VGS<VThr); effectively, you need to raise your gate voltage.  This will be tricky because this circuit will have high gain; you need to carefully adjust VGS DC bias so that Vout sits at about half of your supply voltage.  Once this is done, you should get high gain.

If you want a starting point, disconnect the gate of your NMOS from the source and connect it to your drain (this is called "diode connecting" the device).  Then use the voltage where this settles as your starting point for DC VGS bias.  You can also do a slow sweep on VGS to see the exact point where Vout is half of supply, and use that as your bias point.

The general idea is that you need your bottom FET to be in its high gain region.

Comment: Please see my updated post

Comment: Could you see my updates on the current through M1? Why is it not the same as \$I_{ref}\$? What should current mirror mean?